# Prevent window movement while touching

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch

I've got a scrollviewer wich contains a stackpanel with some images. When I reach the end of the list (using touch interface), if I try to force it, the whole window moves a little bit.

Is there a way to prevent this window movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event of that scrollviewer, in that method write following line.

e.Handled=true;

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you very much